# In-app Billing v3 unable to purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have followed all the guides and references for implementing in-app billing.
as [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html),[here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html),[here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html),[here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html). I have published signed apk into beta, created and activated the products in the console and set up a test account. Everything worked fine and as expected for about ten days. But then suddenly something happened. Now I am unable to succesfully complete a purchase.

I successfully retrieve the details of products via `getSkuDetails()`, bet when trying to buy item via `getBuyIntent()`, the returned bundle is empty, but the response code is 0, which is supposed to be OK. The billing dialog tells me :

```
The item you requested is not available for purchase.
```

In log, there is a line which suggests the purchase indeed failed:

```
D/Finsky(4580): [1] PurchaseFragment.fail: Purchase failed: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=4}
```

I already triple checked the items are activated. I already tried deactivating an item and activating it again. But no luck. I even tried it with an old apk, where it definitely worked some days ago, so the problem is probably in the configuration of the products rather then in app.
Any idea, what the problem might be ?

Comment: @slezadava you have set up test account and same account used in device? have you tried to install app from google play?

Comment: Yay. Test account on device was set alright. But I never installed it from google play, always through adb. When I download it from google play it works. This is really strange, before it worked well from adb before.

Comment: maybe you have updated app version number for development, but which is not published to Google Play?